# Get the value inside span tag and change the background-color as per condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the HTML code for a span

```
<span id = "score" value = {{result['Status']}}  style="color: {{result['Status']}}">&#9873;</span>
```

I want to change the color if the value(value = {{result['Status']}}) in the span is green
I tried using the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var number = document.getElementById("score").innerHTML;

if (number == 'Red') {
 $(span).addClass("Red");
} else if (number == "Gold") {
  $(span).addClass("Gold");
} else if (number == 'Green') {
 $(span).addClass("Green");
}
});
`
```

In the CSS, added the

```
.Green{
color:transparent;
}
```

This is not working for me

Comment: Checking for html value is not the recommended approach. I would suggest you to add some data-attribute and check against that value in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If your backened works the js here should do the trick

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var number = document.getElementById("score");
var color=number.style.color;

if (color == 'red') {
 $('span').addClass("red");
} else if (color == "gold") {
  $('span').addClass("gold");
} else if (color == 'green') {
console.log('green go');
 $('span').addClass("green");
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id = "score" value = 25  style="color: green">&#9873;</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of innerHTMl check value using val()

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
var number = $("#score").val();

if (number == 'Red') {
 $("span#score").addClass("Red");
} else if (number == "Gold") {
  $("span#score").addClass("Gold");
} else if (number == 'Green') {
 $("span#score").addClass("Green");
}
});
```

Hope this helps.